# How to combine search and select with Ant Design ProTable

Tags: typescript, antd, ant-design-pro

Currentyly, I'm using Antd Protable to make a table, and in the search area I have 3 fields which are `ID`, `Status` and `Tax Number` like this

[image]

And this is the column:

```
import { Tag, Select, Form, Input } from "antd";

const FormItem = Form.Item;
const { Option } = Select;


  const columns: ProColumns<API.InvoiceData>[] = [
    {
      title: "ID",
      dataIndex: "id",
      width: "auto"
    },
    {
      title: "Status",
      dataIndex: "status",
      valueType: 'select',
      valueEnum: {
        new: "new",
        expired: "expired",
        approved: "approved",
      }, 
    },
    {
      title: "Tax Number",
      dataIndex: "tax_number",
      width: "auto",
      valueType: 'text',
      renderFormItem: () => {
        return (
          <FormItem name="tax_number" >
            <div style={{ display: "flex"}}>
            <Input />
            <Select placeholder="Select status">
              <Option value="available">Available</Option>
              <Option value="unavailable">Unavailable</Option>
            </Select>
            </div>
          </FormItem>
        );
      },
    },
  ];
```

And this is the ProTable:

```
<ProTable<API.InvoiceData, {}>
                actionRef={actionRef}
                rowKey="id"
                request={async (
                  params: any & {
                    pageSize: number;
                    current: number;
                    keyword: string;
                  }
                ) => {
                  const msg = await InvoiceList({
                    page: params.current,
                    size: params.pageSize,
                    id: params.id,
                    tax_number: params.tax_number,
                    status: params.status,
                  });
                  return {
                    data: msg.data?.invoices,
                    success: msg.result_code == "SUCCESS",
                    total: msg.data?.total
                  };
                }}
                columns={columns}
              />
```

For the first and second field which are `ID` and `Status`, everything works fine. I type anything and press `Query` and it will paste the value into the params and call API.

**My question is in the 3rd field `Tax Number`**. I want to have *both* `search` and `select` for that field. If I input something it would work just like the `ID` field, and if I select a filter option, it would work like the `Status` field, both ways would paste the params tax_number to the query. Right now I can only search, the select component isn't working.
Oh and please note that the `Tax Number` field can only take *one* search option at a time. For example: I cannot `Search` for a something *and* `Select` a filter at the same time. It's only one way or the other.

Any help would be greatly appreciated